# What is Storage Capacity of IndexedDB?

Tags: javascript

I am new to  javaScript based indexedDB . I don't understand how much data can be store in indexeddb.
   Is there any limitations on storage in indexeddb ?

Answer (score 1):

`Firefox` can use `IndexedDB`, `LocalStorage` and `SessionStorage`.

For `IndexedDB`, you can use up to `50MB` on desktop, `5MB` on mobile for free.

`LocalStorage` and `SessionStorage` can use up to `10MB` of storage but the number is actually the sum of both.

For more: [Browser storage limits and eviction criteria](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria)